# Querying Qt Framework Applications for Title Names

Tags: qt

I've got an application that I use for work every day that is built on the Qt framework (Avid Media Composer). I run the Windows version and have an application that hooks various keys and automates some tasks.

For some of the more complex tasks I need to query the Avid application for certain details about its QWidget windows. Is this possible from outside the application?

Clearly using the Win32 API, I can recurse through the windows owned by the particular thread, and get their names (e.g. QWidget), and sizes. However, what I'd really like to know is what the QWidget title is for each window? Is this possible?

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Did you tried to google for `winapi get window title`?

Comment: Yes. The Windows Window title is something like QWidget - you can see it in Spy++. But it's a Qt property I want to snoop.

Comment: I can't understand clearly what are you wanting to get. Is it a title of the window that written on the header? If so, you should just use winapi for that. If it is something else, please describe it more clear, because I (and probably others) cannot understand you.

Comment: @SpongeBobFan Yes. It's the title written on the QWidget header. This is independent of  (and, in my case, different to) the Win32 Windows title that is available through the Win32 API. It is a separate property set through the Qt framework, though I don't know if I can access it without privileged access to the application.

Comment: So it is the title set by `QWidget::setWindowTitle()` method? And it differs from what you getting from Win32 API? And user see the title that was set by `setWindowTitle()`?